# Simple RTMP webcam script?

Tags: ajax, html, flash

Okay I have a rtmp server is there a simple webcam script which I can use to broadcast a webcam to this server I have tried numerous scripts found online however these don't work. I have also asked questions on these scripts I have found online through this forum however haven't had any luck resolving the issues I had with them. Basically I'm after a script which allows a user to broadcast their webcam to an RTMP server. I can provide a rtmp address to test out the script if you can provide one.

Thankyou for any help

Comment: Who/What is your RTMP server? is it Adobe Media Server? or Wowza Server or something else? Anyways what you're asking **almost** sounds like someone should build such a "recorder" and just email it to you for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **[FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)** installed on your computer...

Here is a quick Windows guide (**VFW** capture method) : 
**http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=13**
If you get a list (first code) with device availble and then it also makes an MP4 test file (second code) then you are ready.

However they recommend using **DShow** instead of **VFW**: 
see: **https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow**

If you run `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` in the command prompt you will get a list of devices. One those listed should say "*something camera*". example output looks like: 
`[dshow @ 03ACF580]  "Integrated Camera"`

Test that "Integrated Camera" with this command:
`ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Camera" out.mp4`

Use a command like this below to send to RTMP server (you must be logged in there too)

> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Camera" -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -ab
>   160k -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 30
>   -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -b 1000k -f flv rtmp://yourRTMPServer/Type/yourStreamName

replace **Type** in the link with your stream type (eg: live or VOD or Play or whatever your full RTMP link is written. You did not say so I can only guess its one of these three types).